# Tkinter button executes when the window opens, and not when I click it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following python code with tkinter module. I would like buttons to be an inner function in my code, below is an example where I face the same issue of tkinter button executing itself before I click it

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

def main():
    
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("777x575")
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    text = Text(root, width = 405 , height = 205)
    text.place(x=500, y=10, anchor=S)

    def save():
        Files = [('All Files', '*.*'),
                ('Python Files', '*.py'),
                ('Text Document', '*.txt')]
        file = asksaveasfile(filetypes = Files, defaultextension = Files)

    button = Button(root, text = 'Save', command = lambda : save('Save'))
    button.place(anchor = CENTER, x = 400, y = 500)
    save()

    root.mainloop()
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I have looked at solutions but nothing really has worked for this case. Any suggestions to solve this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: You called `save()` before `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: @acw1668 If I call it after then no window opens if I click button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called save() function before enters mainloop thats why it shows.
Also in button command you called function with a parameter where function doesn't accept any arguments.

```
.
.
.
    text = Text(root, width = 405 , height = 205)
    text.place(x=500, y=10, anchor=S)

    def save():
        Files = [('All Files', '*.*'),
                ('Python Files', '*.py'),
                ('Text Document', '*.txt')]
        file = asksaveasfile(filetypes = Files, defaultextension = Files)

    button = Button(root, text = 'Save', command = lambda : save())
    button.place(anchor = CENTER, x = 400, y = 500)

    root.mainloop()
```

this should work